# Integrating jQuery-File-Upload plugin with blueimp-file-upload-node npm module

Tags: node.js, express, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to integrate the jQuery-File-Upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) with the npm module "blueimp-file-upload-node" to process file uploads.

Sadly, this package "blueimp-file-upload-node" has not been documented yet.

The frontend integration is working correctly, but I am struggling to get the upload functionality working.

I have read and followed this section:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup#using-jquery-file-upload-ui-version-with-nodejs which tells me to start the service by running:
./node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js  (notice, the path of this file is within my node_modules folder)

I would like to have the file uploader as a route of my app, (i.e. /upload) not a separate service, on a different port.

How would I go about that?

My code is here:
https://github.com/robsilva/fileUploader

I really appreciate if anyone can shed some light here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for the express middleware

https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware

Comment: Yeah, I tried this one too. No soup. Have you been able to successfully integrate it with the full-fledged jQuery-File-Upload plugin by any chance?

Comment: I was able to get the "jquery-file-upload-middleware" module working. The problem I was having had to do with my system not having imagemagik installed properly.